# SignalR server closes connection to Unity client right after SSE connection is established

Tags: http, unity-game-engine, mono, signalr, server-sent-events

I'm working on a prototype project connecting a self-hosted SignalR server running on Mono with C# clients (for testing) and Unity clients (representing the actual use-case scenario). The Unity client is using [BestHTTP Pro](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10872) as its SignalR library.

As the WebSocket transport method is not supported on Mono, I'm focusing on server-sent events, and observing very odd behavior there. Communication between server and C# clients is working just fine out of the box. With the Unity client though, the (supposedly) persistent connection is closed immediately after the initial response to the `/signalr/connect` request. No errors are reported anywhere; the response code is 200 in both cases.

Further investigation with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) reveals that the Unity client is sending a `Connection: Keep-Alive` header that the C# client *doesn't* send, to which the server responds with a `Connection: close` header and, well, closing the connection (in other words, exactly the opposite of what the client asks it to do).

Manually removing the keep-alive request header actually makes everything work with the Unity client. Since this feels more like an odd workaround than a correct solution, my question is: Is this strange server-side behavior a bug in the SignalR libraries? Or could Mono be to blame here (I suspect this might be the case)? How can I dig deeper into this, and ideally make the SSE transport work without client-side hacks?

Library versions used:

- [Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR 2.2.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR)
- [BestHTTP Pro 1.9.17](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10872)

For reference, here are the full request/response headers; Unity/BestHTTP client:

```
GET /signalr/connect?tid=1&_=XXX&transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=XXX&connectionData=XXX HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/event-stream
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: XXX
Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive, TE
TE: identity
User-Agent: BestHTTP

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Server: Mono-HTTPAPI/1.0
Date: Wed, 08 Mar 2017 10:34:05 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 73
```

C# client:

```
GET /signalr/connect?clientProtocol=1.4&transport=serverSentEvents&connectionData=XXX&connectionToken=XXX HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: SignalR.Client.NET45/2.2.1.0 (Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0)
Accept: text/event-stream
Host: XXX

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Server: Mono-HTTPAPI/1.0
Date: Wed, 08 Mar 2017 13:11:16 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Keep-Alive: timeout=15,max=99
```

Comment: What are the 73 bytes that the server sends back to the unity client? Could it be an error message?  BTW, keep-alive is the default connection header (if I understood https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection correctly), so my hunch would be some problem on the server (SignalR) side.

Comment: Using curl from the commandline can be a good way to test SSE; you should be able to construct different headers and see what influence they have.

Comment: The 73 bytes are the SignalR response (not an error); it's the same in both cases, there's just no Content-Length header in the other case because the connection stays open, i.e. the response length is not known at the time the server starts sending it.
Yes, it does look like a server-side problem – I'm basically trying to figure out which specific component is causing it (SignalR, Mono, something else?). Good idea about Curl, thanks!

Comment: Note: The project has since moved to .NET Core on the server (with WebSockets support), making this issue irrelevant (plus I'm no longer working on it). Leaving the question open for now though, as it might still be relevant for others.

Answer (score 1):

BestHTTP developer here.

First of all, the plugin can use WebSocket as a SignalR transport on every supported platform. While the mono framework that Unity uses has no WebSocket implementation, the plugin uses its own.

The Server-Sent Events protocol has no direct indication what should be done for a case like this, but modified the plugin to work the same way as other clients. You can wait for the next release on the Asset Store, or you can contact me for an updated package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We were locked on to SSE due to missing WebSockets support on the _server_ side (maybe not entirely clear in the question).
The issue has since become obsolete for this particular project due to a platform change, so I won't be able to check if the new BestHTTP version would have fixed it; still good to know it's being maintained well! :)